# Endless scroll, working in test app, not in real app, rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have searched other questions, and not come up with a answer.

I have the exact same code in a test app which implements endless scroll fine, but the exact same code in my real app is just missfiring and just displaying the normal will paginate links. I am following this tutorial [here](https://richonrails.com/articles/endless-scrolling) and also the railsast 114 on endless scroll and no matter which one i try i get the same dead outcome.

I dont have much experience with javascript and trying to debug through the web debugger but its a whole bunch of code that i am not sure what to look for.

It says in the inspector that "some nodes were hidden. 'show all 102 nodes'" for the test app, where as my real app, does not show this but I cant see why.
There are errors in the css but upon deleting the css and errors resolving, I am still unable to find the problem. I was hoping someone could see if there is a outside reason as to why the exact same code is not working!?

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<div id="users"
<h1>All users</h1>
<%= render @users %>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @users %>
```

user partial

```
<div class="users">
<li>
  <%= user.name %>
</li>
</div>
```

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.pagination').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
      if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200) {
        $('.pagination').text("Please Wait...");
        return $.getScript(url);
      }
    });
    return $(window).scroll();
  }
});
```

view/users/index.js.erb

```
$('#users').append('<%= escape_javascript render(@users) %>');
$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript will_paginate(@users) %>');
```

**Follow Up**

I have set the root of my "real" app to the users#index action and remove all other routes code in my routes.rb file. When I visit the root url the pagination lists all the users as per normal but still, I am unable to get the endless scroll to work. It seems like something else may be wrong somewhere.

Comment: please paste the css errors and javascript errors if there are any (js errors u see in the console log, css errors usually means the css file wasn't included properly , meaning the entire plugin won't have any css to it)

Comment: ok will do, there are no javascript errors, the CSS errors i posted in my question they all dissapear when I delete all my css so cant be that. I will post a follow up to my question, as when i tried to isolate the problem, by only setting the root to the users#index action I still get the same result!

Comment: are u sure the plugin javascript was included? put a console.log("hello world") in app/views/posts/index.js.erb. if u can't see it then that's the problem. Also , seems like there's no css for this plugin just javascript

Comment: a javascript plugin you say? putting console.log("hello world") with teh rest of the code produces a "please wait" in my test app, in my "real" app it just displays the normal pagination.

Comment: OK the 'please wait' is good, but then right after that  it's suppose to make an ajax request (getScript)  to your rails app (which repsonds with a javascript that pushes the new posts to your html). What is happening with that ajax? You can check in the network tab . Is Rails replying with the correct js?

Comment: the last request is a get request to a page 2 in the test app though. The real app is not doing any of this, its just, oblivious to it all it seems.

Comment: What is the result in the network page of this request ? is it empty, is there an error? it should show u something

Comment: it is as you said. 1 html request followed by 8 js requests the last one is a js request to page 2, and two css requests. No error. This is the test app though, which is giving this response to console.log("hello world"). Perhaps we should take this to quick disscussion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134664/discussion-between-lee-eather-and-joel-blum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The tutorial I was following (railstutorial) was using the bootstrap-will-paginate gem, simply removing this gem solved the issue.

As to why it was doing this, I have, yet to figure out, if someone would like to leave a comment as to why that would be great. It applies styling to the links so maybe that was it.